# Java Eclipse Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, java, java-swing, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Estoy creando el videojuego "3 en raya" y soy novato en java.
Tengo creado todo y no me da error de sintaxis.Alguien me puede decir por que no me aparece ningun mensaje cuando pongo 3 cruces o circulos seguidos? 
Dejo aqui mi codigo

```
public class TicTacToes {

    private JFrame frame;
    private String startGame = "X";
    private int oCount = 0;
    private int xCount = 0;
    private JLabel btn1;
    private JLabel btn2;
    private JLabel btn3;
    private JLabel btn4;
    private JLabel btn5;
    private JLabel btn6;
    private JLabel btn7;
    private JLabel btn8;
    private JLabel btn9;
    private JTextField txtCountX;
    private JTextField txtCountO;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TicTacToes window = new TicTacToes();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TicTacToes() {
        initialize();

    }

    private void GameScore() {
        txtCountX.setText(String.valueOf(xCount++));
        txtCountO.setText(String.valueOf(oCount++));
    }

    private void choosePlayer() {
        if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){
            startGame = "O";
        }
        else {
            startGame = "X";
        }
    }

    private void WinningGame() {
        String b1 = btn1.getText();
        String b2 = btn2.getText();
        String b3 = btn3.getText();
        String b4 = btn4.getText();
        String b5 = btn5.getText();
        String b6 = btn6.getText();
        String b7 = btn7.getText();
        String b8 = btn8.getText();
        String b9 = btn9.getText();

        //COMBINACIONES PARA QUE X GANA

    if (b1 == "X" && b2 == "X" && b3 == "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jugador con las X gana");

    xCount ++;
    GameScore();

    }

    if (b1 == ("X") && b4 == ("X") && b7 == ("X")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jugador con las X gana",
                "Tic Tac Toe",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    xCount ++;
    GameScore();

    }

    if (b1 == ("X") && b5 == ("X") && b9 == ("X")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jugador con las X gana",
                "Tic Tac Toe",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    xCount ++;
    GameScore();

    }

    //COMBINACIONES PARA QUE O GANA

        if (b1 == ("O") && b2 == ("O") && b3 == ("O")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jugador con las O gana",
                    "Tic Tac Toe",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        xCount ++;
        GameScore();}

        if (b1 == ("O") && b4 == ("O") && b7 == ("O")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jugador con las O gana",
                    "Tic Tac Toe",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        xCount ++;
        GameScore();}

        if (b1 == ("O") && b5 == ("O") && b9 == ("O")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jugador con las O gana",
                    "Tic Tac Toe",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        xCount ++;
        GameScore();

        }



    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1200, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 5, 2, 2));

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("");
        btn1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn1.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn1.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        panel_1.add(btn1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("");
        btn2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn2.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn2.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        panel_2.add(btn2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_3);
        panel_3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("");
        btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn3.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn3.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn3.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        btn3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        panel_3.add(btn3, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
        panel_4.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_4);
        panel_4.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel gh = new JLabel("Jugador X:");
        gh.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        gh.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        panel_4.add(gh, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_5 = new JPanel();
        panel_5.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_5);
        panel_5.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        txtCountX = new JTextField();
        txtCountX.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtCountX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 75));
        txtCountX.setText("0");
        panel_5.add(txtCountX, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        txtCountX.setColumns(10);

        JPanel panel_6 = new JPanel();
        panel_6.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_6);
        panel_6.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn4 = new JButton("");
        btn4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn4.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn4.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn4.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        panel_6.add(btn4, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_7 = new JPanel();
        panel_7.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_7);
        panel_7.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn5 = new JButton("");
        btn5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn5.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn5.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn5.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        btn5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        panel_7.add(btn5, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_8 = new JPanel();
        panel_8.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_8);
        panel_8.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn6 = new JButton("");
        btn6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn6.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn6.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn6.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        btn6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        panel_8.add(btn6, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_9 = new JPanel();
        panel_9.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_9);
        panel_9.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel lbPlayerO = new JLabel("Jugador O:");
        lbPlayerO.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbPlayerO.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        panel_9.add(lbPlayerO, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_10 = new JPanel();
        panel_10.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_10);
        panel_10.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        txtCountO = new JTextField();
        txtCountO.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtCountO.setText("0");
        txtCountO.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 75));
        panel_10.add(txtCountO, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        txtCountO = new JTextField();
        txtCountO.setText("0");
        txtCountO.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtCountO.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 75));
        panel_10.add(txtCountO, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        txtCountO.setColumns(10);
        txtCountO.setColumns(10);

        JPanel panel_11 = new JPanel();
        panel_11.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_11);
        panel_11.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn7 = new JButton("");
        btn7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn7.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn7.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn7.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();

            }
        });
        btn7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        panel_11.add(btn7, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_12 = new JPanel();
        panel_12.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_12);
        panel_12.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn8 = new JButton("");
        btn8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn8.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn8.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn8.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();
            }
        });
        btn8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        panel_12.add(btn8, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_13 = new JPanel();
        panel_13.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_13);
        panel_13.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btn9 = new JButton("");
        btn9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn9.setText(startGame);
                if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                    btn9.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                else {
                    btn9.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                choosePlayer();
                WinningGame();
            }
        });
        btn9.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 95));
        panel_13.add(btn9, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_14 = new JPanel();
        panel_14.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_14);
        panel_14.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
        btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn1.setText(null);
                btn2.setText(null);
                btn3.setText(null);
                btn4.setText(null);
                btn5.setText(null);
                btn6.setText(null);
                btn7.setText(null);
                btn8.setText(null);
                btn9.setText(null);
            }
        });
        btnReset.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
        panel_14.add(btnReset, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel_15 = new JPanel();
        panel_15.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panel.add(panel_15);
        panel_15.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame = new JFrame("Exit");
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "¿Quieres salir del juego?", "Tic Tac Toe",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)== JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) {

                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
        });
        btnExit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
        panel_15.add(btnExit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Comment: que mensaje deberia aparecer??? en donde de todo este codigo esta eso?

Comment: Cuando se pone 3 x seguidas, deberia aparecer el mensaje "Jugador con las X gana ", no? lo pone cuando pongo las combinaciones b1 == "X", b3 == "X"...

Comment: Fijate que de todo tu codigo, no se entiende como va. trata de dejar solo lo importante del mismo.. y otra cosa, las condiciones para ganar en ta te ti no son 3.. son 8...

Comment: Lo importante del codigo es el metodo  WinningGame, con el quiero que si pulso 3 botones en linea poniendo en ellos la X  me salga un mensaje donde diga que has ganado. Sin embargo parece que nunca se llega a cumplir la condicion y por tanto no aparece ningun mensaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Es tremendamente confuso y para nada recomendado cuando propones unos `JLabel` y `JButton` con el mismo nombre! (`btn1 ... btn9`).
2. **Siempre** las comparaciones de igualdad del tipo de dato `String` se efectúan a través del método `equals()` **no con** `==`.

   ```
   if(b1 == ("O") && b5 == ("O") && b9 == ("O"))//Incorrecto!

   if(b1.equals("O") && b5.equals("O") && b9.equals("O"))//Manera correcta
   ```

Ocurre que los `JLabel` en ningún momento estan siendo instanciados, no existen, por ende en el método `WinningGame()` se obtiene el `NullPointerException`.

Ya que usas `JButton` para registrar los *clicks* pues entonces trabajemos con ellos cambiándoles el *scope* para que sean globales y no que solo queden a nivel del método `initialize()`:

```
/*private JLabel btn1;
private JLabel btn2;
private JLabel btn3;
private JLabel btn4;
private JLabel btn5;
private JLabel btn6;
private JLabel btn7;
private JLabel btn8;
private JLabel btn9;*/
private JButton btn1;
private JButton btn2;
private JButton btn3;
private JButton btn4;
private JButton btn5;
private JButton btn6;
private JButton btn7;
private JButton btn8;
private JButton btn9;
private JTextField txtCountX;
private JTextField txtCountO;
//...
//...
private void initialize() {
 //...
 btn1=new JButton("");
 btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     btn1.setText(startGame);
     if (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
       btn1.setForeground(Color.RED);
     } else {
       btn1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
     }
     choosePlayer();
     WinningGame();
   }
  });
  panel_1.add(btn1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  //demas botones demas atributos...
}
```

He probado y camina bien; de resto solo queda agregar las condiciones que hacen falta para determinar si gana ***X*** u ***O***.

Comment: Muchisimas gracuas johnnyTB, soy principiante en java y me cuesta un poquillo. Un saludo :D

Comment: Muchisimas gracuas johnnyTB, soy principiante en java y me cuesta un poquillo. Un saludo :D